# Makefile won't display colors

Tags: command-line, bash, make, colors

I'm currently trying to display all the Makefile targets to build a `make help` command and I got it working by doing:

```
help:
    @grep -E '^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+:.*?## .*$$' $(MAKEFILE_LIST) \
    | sed -n "s/^\(.*\): \(.*\)##\(.*\)/$(printf '\033[0;1;31m')\1$(printf '\033[0m') \2 \3/p" \
    | column -t -s '##'
```

As you can see in the sed command, I'm displaying the first column (the target name) in red.

Now when I run this command in the shell the output is perfectly fine, the color is showing. But when I run the `make help`, all the text is white.

Is there something I'm missing in the command or is there a way to 'enable' color for Makefiles ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to escape the `$` signs in the `$(printf...)` parts by doubling them to `$$`, so `make` is doing that part itself and does not find an expansion. If you prefer you can use `$(shell printf '\033[0;1;31m')` to have make run the command.